# jQuery.text() - How can I alter text of tag without affecting any sub-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I am writing a small jQuery plugin to allow inline editing (for my purposes I want a very small lightweight custom plugin).  Everything works great except when I update the original tag with the new value it removes the edit image used to instigate editing, and as such no further edits are allowed.

I tried to the following, with replaces the edit image but the edit image no longer has the `click` handler associated with it.

The html looks a little like this

```
<h2 class="inlineEdit">Thing to edit<a href='' class='pencil_edit_image'></a></h2>
```

The javascript looks like:

```
var editThis = $(".inlineEdit");

var existinglink = editThis.find(".pencil_edit_image");
editThis.text($(this).val());
editThis.append(existinglink);
```

How best can I accomplish this?

Comment: what does `editThis` contain?

Comment: It is the `h2` itself, updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried detaching it before it is replaced?

```
var existinglink = editThis.find(".pencil_edit_image");
existingLink.detach();
editThis.text($(this).val());
editThis.append(existinglink);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have support for text nodes, so the easiest is to put the text in an element so that you can easily access it:

```
<h2 class="inlineEdit"><span class="editable">Thing to edit></span><a href='' class='pencil_edit_image'></a></h2>

 $(".inlineEdit .editable").text($(this).val());
```

To access the text node without adding an extra element, you can use the DOM element:

```
 $(".inlineEdit")[0].firstChild.innerHTML = $(this).val();
```